# Google Sheet - Sum Column until value is met if another column matches

Tags: google-sheets

Column A is trx date
Column B is a stock ticker
Column C is qty of shares purchased
column D is qty of shares sold
Column E is transaction price
Column F is trx total

I would like to have a formula I enter the ticker and number of shares I currently have. And it gives me the sum of column F until C has reached that many shares.

For example I currently have 356 shares of DKNG i would like a formula to sum the column F until the sum of column c is >= 356 and column b is dkng.

I'm at a total loss here. [image]

Comment: Please Share an editable copy of your sheet. Update your question with that link. Also, what you want to happen is not very clear. Please add to your demo sheet an example of the inputs you would type in, plus a manually calculated example of whatever output you want to be automatic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Would you lease explain how you calculate that you "currently have 356 shares of DKNG". My calculation  is 756 and there is never a date on which there is a balance of 356.